# Cant return manually generated id

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to return the value of new_id but with no success. Any help?

```
create or replace FUNCTION create_election (name        VARCHAR, 
                             description VARCHAR, 
                           type          VARCHAR, 
                           subtype       VARCHAR, 
                           started_at    VARCHAR, 
                           ended_at      VARCHAR) 
RETURN INT
IS
v_id int;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO election VALUES  ( 
          (  SELECT nvl(max(id)+1, 0) AS new_id FROM  election ) , 
          name,  description,  type, subtype, started_at, ended_at, 
          0,  0,  0 
) RETURNING new_id into v_id ;
END;
```

--- UPDATE ---
I choose the solution based on best practices. Thx for the help.

Comment: `select count(1) from election` returns 0(zero) i think, i mean no_data_found exception raises.

Comment: The Insert query is correct. the problem is that with sql only i cant get the new_id, I need pl/sql for what I searched. Didnt get ur comment though.

Comment: ... RETURN v_id; END;

Comment: @tbone but I need to assign a value to v_id, I am getting an error in the into keyword.

Comment: and what is the error?  Also, make v_id a number or pls_integer maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using queries like `SELECT nvl(max(id)+1, 0) AS new_id FROM  election` to generate IDs is a bad practice. You will get duplicated values each time, when two or more users will invoke this function.

Oracle has sequences for this. Sequences always generate unique values. First, create sequence:

```
create sequence election_seq;
```

Then use it in your function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION create_election (name        VARCHAR, 
                             description VARCHAR, 
                           type          VARCHAR, 
                           subtype       VARCHAR, 
                           started_at    VARCHAR, 
                           ended_at      VARCHAR) 
RETURN INT
IS
v_id int;
BEGIN
  v_id := election_seq.nextval;
  INSERT INTO election VALUES  
  (v_id, name,  description,  type, subtype, started_at, ended_at, 0,  0,  0);
END;
```

Comment: Thx I was trying to dodge sequences thinking they were complex. Although I am curious to know the solution to my problem in the way I was doing it.

Comment: @Goamaral See other answers to that. Thay all seem working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add select into before insert as

```
  SELECT nvl(max(id)+1, 0) into v_id  FROM  election
```

And use `v_id` later in insert and return .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this line before the END which ends the function:

```
RETURN v_id;
```

You are getting the data into the local variable v_id but not returning it from the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace FUNCTION create_election (name        VARCHAR, 
                             description VARCHAR, 
                           type          VARCHAR, 
                           subtype       VARCHAR, 
                           started_at    VARCHAR, 
                           ended_at      VARCHAR) 
RETURN INT
IS
  v_id int;
  new_id int;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO election VALUES  ( 
          nvl(  (SELECT max(id)+1 AS new_id FROM  election) ,1 ), 
          name,  description,  type, subtype, started_at, ended_at, 
          0,  0,  0  
) RETURNING new_id into v_id ;

  return v_id;
END;
```